# Nginx showing 404 Not Found for every page but homepage

Tags: php, web-services, .htaccess, nginx, vps

I am trying to run a php app on nginx server on ubuntu. I did put all my files in var/www/mydomain.com.html It's rendering my index.php perfectly. But showing 404 Not Found for every other page even though those files are exists in the same directory.

Here is my server block configuration.

```
server {
listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
listen   [::]:80; ## listen for ipv6

root /var/www/app.limoposter.com/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name app.limoposter.com www.app.limoposter.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

}

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have an .htaccess which routes every request to your index.php
Since nginx doesn't understand .htaccess files, you'll have to rewrite this using nginx
See https://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Edit:
I downloaded your .htaccess and used the converter mentioned above:
This is the output:

```
autoindex off;
location / {
if ($script_filename !~ "-d"){
rewrite ^/login/(.*)/$ /login.php?type=$1 break;
}
if ($script_filename !~ "-d"){
rewrite ^/dashboard/(.*)/$ /dashboard.php?show=$1 break;
}
if ($script_filename !~ "-d"){
rewrite ^/admin/(.*)/$ /admin.php?module=$1 break;
}
if ($script_filename !~ "-d"){
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1.php break;
}
if ($request_uri ~ "storage/(\d+)_(.*)$"){
rewrite ^/storage/(\d+)_(\d+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)$ /download.php?folder=$1_$2&file=$3.$4 break;
}
}
```

Comment: Should I put this rewrited htaccess in the server block, nginx.conf or anywhere else?

Comment: This should work but to have it more organized you could create an extra file

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)